# SQL Server 2012 Arbitrarily Slow Performance

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I am having a peculiar issue involving Microsoft SQL Server 2012. We are taking a table with a large set of data and copying it to another table where it will later be run through a series of stored procedures. We are using an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement to copy the data from one table to the other.

We transfer data often using this process and it is usually very fast. However, we just encountered one set of data that seems to be taking significantly longer to copy. There are no more rows in the table than usual. We are baffled as to what would make this one particular set of data copy slower than others since there is nothing physically different about this data other than the values of the fields in each row.

One thing to note is that this data is actually different than most that we process in that it originally was in a table in SQL Server 2008 before we brought it into SQL Server 2012 to be processed. We attempted to run the same queries on that data on the 2008 server and we experienced no performance issues.

We are unsure about the root of this problem and are unsure where to begin to resolve this. If anybody has ever experienced this or has any advice that would be great.

Comment: Do you observe blocking while the slow copy is running? `sp_who2`. Is the schema of the slow table the same as with the other tables? Does the problem go away after rebuilding all indexes?

Comment: Do you still have a "fast" set of table data and a "slow" set of table data?  Is there a significant difference in data size with regard to [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776(v=sql.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have one env not working and the other working happily with the same dataset, I would suggest that as the fastest way to identify what is different.  You can get a profiler trace up on both and look at the process running through to see if you can identify a bottleneck or something fundamentally different.